# Dynamic JSON reference

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to refer to the primary phone number in this array

```
"phone":[{"label":"Fax","value":"234-345-5678","primary":false},{"label":"main","value":"456-234-2345","primary":false},{"label":"main","value":"456-456-4567","primary":true}]
```

I'm using the following php:

```
"person_phone" => $phoneNumbers['phone'][2]['value'];
```

But the `primary` phone may not be the 3rd item within an, so is there a way to evaluate the `"primary":true` of the array element before deciding to refer to it.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this question got voted down. It asks a question that I couldn't find the answer to anywhere on the web, and it's properly formatted. If there's anything I can do to improve the question, please comment it below.

Comment: Why not loop through the elements using a `foreach()` and a `break` to search for the primary?

Comment: @halfer Because my json data is extremely nested. The example just shows a basic example of what I'm trying to do. The actual json reference I would need to do to get to `[phone][arrayValue][value]` would be like this: `$returnedData[data][$rowNum][person][phone][0][value]`

Comment: Unless you are willing to change the format of your data, you have no choice - you need to iterate over the array and search. I don't quite follow the format of the array you've presented in your comment - are you saying there is too much data to loop over? How many entries are there in your array? I presume you only need to loop over as many numbers as a person has, so there will only ever be a handful, right?

Comment: @halfer I iterate over my array with a `for` loop that goes through each `$rowNum` once. I'm having trouble conceptualizing how I would iterate through the `phone` array after I iterate through the whole `json data`. I think it may look like this `for ($z=0; $z<$2; $z++){if ($response[data][$x][person_id][phone][$z][primary]="false"){return $response[data][$x][person_id][phone][$z][value]; }}`

Comment: Yes, roughly speaking. Note that the equality operator is `==` in PHP, and string array indexes should be quoted (e.g. `$response['data']...`) rather than left bare. By `$2` I think you meant just `2`, as well.

Comment: (Presenting code in comments is, as you can see, not very clear. It is even less so when parts are commented out. Always present the minimum required, otherwise the issue at hand can become confused).

Comment: My apologies. Disregard my question.

Comment: Not disregarded - just friendly advice! `:-)`

Comment: One last question. When you say the equal operator in php, is that just for condition statement like `if`or do I use the `==` for initializing variables and any other time I'm setting something equal to another.

Comment: The equality operator (`==`) just does a comparison. It it is mainly used in `if()` statements, but you can use it anywhere a boolean would be specified. So `addIce($drink == 'lemonade')` will call the `addIce()` function with a boolean (true if it is lemonade, false otherwise). However a single equals sign is an assignment, so we can say `$whiskyAge = 15;`.

Comment: There's some [variables information here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a single "simple" array reference. PHP's arrays "paths" aren't searchable as if you had XPath or something. You'd have to loop on your array to find the "primary" record, then access the number once found:

```
foreach($records as $phone) {
   if ($phone['primary']) {
       return $phone['value'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array_reduce will return this array `{"label":"main","value":"456-456-4567","primary":true}`. And you can take any value, you need

```
$val = array_reduce($arr['phone'], function ($c,$a) {  if($a["primary"]) $c = $a;  return $c;}, []);
echo $val['value'];
```